# How to host blog on separate domain from main site

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping, customization

### Question

I have two established, non-WordPress sites with basic LAMP stacks: `mysite1.com` and `mysite2.com`.  I'd like to set up mysite1.com/blog and `mysite2.com/blog` as WordPress blogs.  What is the best way to set up WordPress for this?

### Assumptions

1. I've read WordPress can have problems being installed in a
   subfolder, and believe it will be much easier to host WordPress at
   `myothersite1.com` and have
   `mysite1.com/blog/sometopic/somepost` pull the page from
   `myothersite1.com/blog/sometopic/somepost`. (I am already able to do this).
2. I've read `mysite.com/blog` is better for SEO than `blog.mysite.com`, so I'd like to use this approach.
3. I think I want to use multi-site instead of two separate WordPress installations, and can use `myothersite2.com` or `myothersite3.com` if needed.

### Concern

I want to ensure that all links and canonical page headers use `mysite1.com`, and not `myothersite1.com`.

Anyone know of any articles on this?  Any considerations that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Assumption 1

Wrong. I have a couple of WordPress installations in subfolders, some redirected to sub-domain, some not. If you set up the setting properly, there isn't any issue with this.

Searching for *"problem + WordPress + subfolder"* will lead to some questions, that turn out to be having rewrite rule problems.

### Assumption 2

If you are relying on SEO factors purposed by websites such as WooRank, then you shouldn't really bother. These services offer some good recommendations, but their methods are not *"Divine"*. Search engines are smarter than what they were a decade ago.

You're not going to lose 50% traffic just because you choose to use `blog.example.com` over `example.com/blog`.

What if your site is a blog itself? should it have another `example.com/blog`? No.

### Assumptions 3

You can go either multisite or two individual installations. Multisite offers some features, such as shared users data, which you might find useful.